# Given a real sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined as $x_1=2$ and $ x_{n+1}=\sqrt{3}+\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2-1}},\forall~ n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\bullet~$ **Problem:** Given a real sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined as
$$\begin{cases}
x_1=2;\\
x_{n+1}=\sqrt{3}+\dfrac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_n^2-1}},\forall~ n=1,2,... \end{cases}$$
Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent and find that limit.

---

---

$\blacksquare~$ **Claim $1$:** The substitution $x_n \to \text{cosec}(t_n)$ is well defined.

$\blacksquare~$ **Proof:** We have to show that $x_n > 1$ (The bound can be made more strict, namely $x_n > \sqrt{3}$) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ We'll use induction in that case.

- For $n = 1$, we have that $x_n = 2 > 1$
- For $n = k$, let's assume that $x_k > 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}.$
- For $n = k + 1,$ we have that
  $$ x_{k + 1} = \sqrt{3} + \frac{x_k}{\sqrt{x_k^2 - 1}} > \sqrt{3} > 1 $$

Hence the transformation $x_n \to \text{cosec}(t_n)$ is well defined.

---

---

$\bullet~$ **My Question:** Can trigonometric transformation help?

If we consider $ x_{n} = \text{cosec}{(t_{n})} $ for some real sequence $\{ t_{n} \}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x_{1} = 2\\
x_{n + 1} = \sqrt{3} + \dfrac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_{n}^2 - 1}} & \text{for any } n \in \mathbb{N} 
\end{cases} 
\equiv \begin{cases}
t_{1} = \dfrac{\pi}{6}\\
\text{cosec}(t_{n + 1}) = \sqrt{3} + \dfrac{\text{cosec}(t_n)}{\sqrt{\text{cosec}^2(t_{n})- 1}} & \text{for any } n \in \mathbb{N} 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}And hence we have that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$\text{cosec}(t_{n + 1}) = \sqrt{3} + \text{sec}(t_{n})$$And we know that for $x \in \bigg[  -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\bigg] - \{ 0 \}$, $$ \text{cosec}(x) = \text{sec}\bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - x \bigg) $$Then can we use these in-order to boil down the problem? I don't have anything solid yet.

---

$\bullet~$ **Considering the limit exists:**
If the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ is convergent, say to $L \in [\sqrt{3}, 3] $. Then we have that
$$ L = \sqrt{3} + \frac{L}{\sqrt{L^2 - 1}} \implies L = \sqrt{3} \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} $$

---

Comment: I am not sure if the trig subsitution is helping in any way. You can prove it in the usual ways -1) prove $x_n < L$ by induction. Then using that 2) prove $x_{n+1}>x_n$ and then you are done.

Comment: @dezdichado yeah, I have done it in that way. But I was just curious if the problem can be approached in this way.

Comment: You could also [investigate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3Dsqrt%283%29+%2B+x%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2-1%29) $f(x)=\sqrt{3} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ and conclude it's a [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping).

Comment: @rtybase I know these methods. I was curious about the trig transformation thing. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: considering $L = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{15}}{2}$ is not a trig value of any well-known angles, I highly doubt that a trig substitution approach will simplify your problem. Conceivably, you can substitute $y_n = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}x_n$ and notice that $y_n\to\sin(18^\circ),$ so you might be able to do something there. But my hunch says no.